# not able to sudo apt-get upgrade and also on top red minus sign

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libicu-dev : Depends: libicu55 (= 55.1-7ubuntu0.2) but 55.1-7 is installed
 libicu55 : Breaks: libicu55:i386 (!= 55.1-7) but 55.1-7ubuntu0.2 is installed
 libicu55:i386 : Breaks: libicu55 (!= 55.1-7ubuntu0.2) but 55.1-7 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Please help!SOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this command:

```
sudo apt install libicu55=55.1-7ubuntu0.2
```

And if its not work, use can use this one:

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-all libicu55 libicu55:i386
sudo apt install libicu-dev
sudo apt install -f
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66030/discussion-on-answer-by-ali76-not-able-to-sudo-apt-get-upgrade-and-also-on-top-r).